# Rails Constraints and Heroku Sub Subdomains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, dns, subdomain

I have a Rails app I'm testing that uses constraints to define a subdomain (cgc) for certain routes. Locally, everything works as expected. Pushing my code to the staging app on Heroku however, the subdomain doesn't work.

I've tried setting up CNAME records so that `staging.our-website.com` points to `our-app.herokuapp.com`, and another CNAME record for `cgc.staging.our-website.com` that also points to `our-app.herokuapp.com`. Both of these domains have also been added to the app itself in Heroku, and both are routing to the index of the application. The end result I would like is for the "cgc" subdomain to be handled by Rails so that `cgc.staging.our-website.com goes to the intended pages.

If all goes well in staging, the final home for the apps will be `our-website.com` and `cgc.our-website.com` respectively - not sure if this impacts the potential solutions.

Comment: Did you ever find a way to do this on Heroku? Having the same issue now.

Comment: @samlester For setup in Heroku, we've done a few things. First, we have a constraint in our routes defined to pick up the subdomain we would like, (i.e. constraints subdomain: /^cgc?$/). Then in Heroku, we added 'cgc.our-domain.com' as a domain for our site, and finally we have a CNAME record for '*.our-domain.com' pointing to our Heroku app that enables us to add subdomains at will using the routes file. We also moved our staging site to it's own domain (i.e. 'our-cdomain-staging.com') since the 'cgc.staging.our-domain' wasn't working properly. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for the info – really useful. Got it working using the regex subdomain constraint and with the app.staging.domain.com CNAME record pointing to Heroku. Using [Pow](http://pow.cx/) to get the subdomains working locally too.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how you have your routing set up, but if you do something like the following:

```
constraints(subdomain: /^cgc(\.|$)/) do
    # Any subdomain-only matches here
end
```

Then you'll match both 'cgc' as subdomain, as well as 'cgc.whatever-in-here', which should meet your needs :)

The problem is that Rails treats everything before the root domain name as the subdomain, rather than just the first portion.  I'm not sure which is *technically* correct.

**Followup**:

In order to fix the problem I noted about (about Rails and subdomain handling), you may want to look at the

```
config.action_dispatch.tld_length
```

setting.  Increasing it beyond 1 means that additional subdomain portions get treated as part of the main domain for the purpose of URL generation.  Note that this will probably affect how the "subdomain" matcher works, but I haven't verified that.

Comment: Appreciate the answers pnomolos, but the constraints in our routes file wasn't the issue. It ended up having something to do with the way we set up the DNS for our staging site - Rails wasn't picking up 'cgc.staging.our-domain.com' as the cgc subdomain, and I'm assuming that's because it's a sub-sub domain. We ended up moving our staging site to it's own URL (i.e. 'our-domain-staging.com') and that appears to have fixed the problem.

Comment: @lukad03 - The `config.action_dispatch.tld_length` setting may have helped fix that (so that 'cgc' was considered the subdomain, rather than 'cgc.staging'), but glad to hear you got it working :)